# Will touching poop of any animal make me impure?

Tags: taharah

Let's say a crow pooped on my shirt.

If I offer prayer while wearing the shirt without washing, will my prayer be valid? I want to know if impurity passes with animal poops.

Comment: First of all a believer is Tahir (pure) by default. Taharah is only relevant in the context of acts of worship. Therefore this question is not well posed

Comment: Okay but everyone will understand what I meant and I was told to summarize the question when posting.

Comment: Who said this: You should give a full description including all what si necessary to answer.  Your question is something where anybody would say: yeah you should wash it, but why do you post this on IslamSE?

Comment: What I meant by 'do I need to wash it' is, if I pray without cleaning the dirt from my shirt, will my be valid? + Edited the description of the question so that everyone can understand.

Comment: Then please edit your post and give a full description of what you want to have answered. Comments are not meant to last forever. One liners are low quality questions!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. And I have edited the question and now it's 3 liner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the animal is not edible (not halal) then its feces and urine is impure according to the majority opinion. And the same applies to the droppings of birds whose flesh is not lawful. A crow is included in this.

> جمهور الفقهاء على أن ذرق الطيور التي لا يؤكل لحمها كالباز والشاهين والرخم والغراب والحدأة نجس
>
> The majority of jurists are of the view that the excrement of birds whose meat cannot be eaten is impure such as that of an eagle, hawk, vulture, crow and kite
>
> <sup>— [Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah 21/211](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/12991)</sup>

If the animal or bird is edible then there is difference of opinion among the scholars. The cautionary approach is to wash it.

Opinions which consider such excretions to be impure are based on generalization of the following ahadith:

> استنزهوا من البول
>
> Beware of urine
>
> <sup>— [Bulugh al-Maram](https://sunnah.com/bulugh:103)</sup>

> وألقى الروثة وقال  هي رجس
>
> He threw the dung away, saying: 'It is impure.'
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:156) ,  [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:314)</sup>

Whereas opinions which consider them to be pure are based on the fact that protecting oneself from these materials is difficult. And based on their interpretation of the hadith of praying anywhere on earth including in the sheep folds.

Answer (score 0):

If these animals are among those whose meat is permissible to eat according to sharee’ah, such as sparrows, chickens, ducks... sheep, cows, horses...etc.etc, their dung is pure

Comment: That depends on the school of thought.